# SystemExit: 2 ap.parse_args()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm using InceptionV4 from [here][1]

but i got this error message

```
SystemExit
2
  File "C:\Labbb\inception\InceptionV4-master\inceptionv4.py", line 53, in <module>
    args = vars(ap.parse_args(args=[]))
SystemExit: 2
```

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()

ap.add_argument("-g", "--gpus", default=1, type=int,
        help="# of available GPUs")
ap.add_argument("-train", "--train_dir", type=str, default="train/",
    help="train directory")
ap.add_argument("-val", "--val_dir", type=str, default="val/",
        help="val directory")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--checkpoint", type=str, default="no")
ap.add_argument("-classes", "--num_classes", type=int, required=True)
ap.add_argument("-epochs", "--epochs", type=int, default=1000)
ap.add_argument("-steps", "--steps_per_epoch", type=int, default=500)
ap.add_argument("-lr", "--learning_rate", type=float, default='1e-3')
ap.add_argument("-log", "--log_dir", type=str, default="logs/")
#args = vars(ap.parse_args())

args = vars(ap.parse_args(args=[]))
```

I tried to add "args=[])" but not work

and I remove required from this line, but appear another error

```
#ap.add_argument("-classes", "--num_classes", type=int, required=True)
ap.add_argument("-classes", "--num_classes", type=int)

TypeError
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
  File "C:\Labbb\inception\InceptionV4-master\inceptionv4.py", line 213, in <module>
    def create_inception_v4(nb_classes=int(args["num_classes"]), load_weights=check):
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

I modified args["num_classes"] to args[6] , still not work
[1]: https://github.com/systemcorp-ai/InceptionV4/blob/master/inceptionv4.py

Comment: Why did you add `args=[]`?

Comment: Right, you definitely do not want `args=[]`, because you want it to read the command-line arguments.  Do you understand what arguments the command line requires?  You MUST specify `-classes=N` for some N when you run this script.